# SwiftyJSON type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to create a JSON dictionary using SwiftyJSON:

```
    let addressAttributes: JSON = [
        "latitude": address.latitudeFloat,
        "longitude": address.longitudeFloat,
        "street_1": address.street1,
        "street_2": address.street2,
        "city": address.city,
        "state_code": address.stateCode,
        "zip_code": address.zipCode
    ]
```

Unfortunately, I get the warning that the `type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. I have both `String?` and `Float?` optionals here.

What am I missing?

If I remove the `Float?` values from the dictionary, I then get `Cannot convert value of type '[String: String?]' to specified type 'JSON'`.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `let addressAttributes: JSON = JSON(["what":ever])`

Comment: I was trying the syntax found here https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#literal-convertibles

Comment: Does it have to do with optionals needing unwraps? In the scenario with removed floats, did you try explicitly unwrapping all the strings? `address.stateCode!`?

Comment: I think it is an issue with optionals. This is real pain. Is there some sort of pattern for assembling JSON dynamically? I have to loop through several data structures to assemble nested JSON a couple layers deep.

Comment: I only read JSON atm so I've never had to create one dynamically. Is it saying it wants an optional as the value? If so I think it would be 'fairly' trivial to solve. In your loop, just create an optional of the data type you want with a helper function. `if(type == String) createOptionalString()`

Comment: No I mean that it won't use optionals. I have to unwrap them. But this doesn't solve the problem of needing to combine JSON later on, even if I solve this here.

Comment: Im not clear on how thats an issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92193/discussion-between-josh-smith-and-aggressor).